# Canon EOS rebel 2000 35mm won’t turn on

Tags: battery

I dug out this 35mm film camera from a drawer at my parents. It wouldn’t turn on so I replaced the battery but it still won’t turn on. Any advice?! I’d love to get it up and running if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Camera manuals can be downloaded for free from https://www.butkus.org/chinon/

Comment: There is no advice someone can give you remotely, based on the generic "not working" description you've given. It's not really any different to calling up a mechanic and telling them simply that your car won't turn on. Well, the difference compared to a car is that it might not be economical to even investigate why a cheapo plastic/electronic SLR is not operating as expected. You can probably buy another on eBay for less than the cost of a repair technician's time.